# How to use URL Connection Class to send FTP in Java

Tags: java, url, ftp

really Unsure as to why this is not working. I get a successful out put with no exception; however, when I check the FTP repository, nothing gets sent. Cannot use apache.commons due to being on a corporate network, and my company does not have the specific library in its repository.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Collection;


class SendAmpFeed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        uploadFTP();
    }

    public static void uploadFTP() {

        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
        String ftpURL = "ftp://anonymous:anonymous@blabla.web.blabla.com//xxx/yyyp;";
        String filepath = "H:/myFolder/textFile.txt;

        //ftpURL = String.format(ftpURL, user, pwd, hostname,uploadpath);
        //System.out.println("Upload URL: " + ftpURL);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(ftpURL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println(inputStream.read());
            }


            System.out.println("File Successfully uploaded");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Output: 

118

103

108

114

-1

File Successfully uploaded
```

Comment: *`System.out.println(inputStream.read());`* is wrong as it will cause another read. I would try doing `conn.setDoOutput(true)` too. And close the output stream

Comment: Check your filename again, now its ending in semicolon "yyyp;". FTP server might assume you will give typecode after the semicolon but there is no typecode after it... Refer here: [link](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/ftp/use-urlconnection-to-download-file-from-ftp-server))

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but I had implemented a simple FTP client for  school project a few years ago. You can go ahead and have a look at the code, checking on whether you can use parts of it

https://github.com/Kortex/Simple-FTP-Client